# Varying Vagrant Vagrants - How to Edit Plugin

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

I got VVV running on my new MAC OS 10. The issue is I have never used VVV before and frankly I'm not certain which files I should be looking for or editing.

I'd like to local the wp-content folder on the local dev server,this way I can edit my plugin locally.

Here are the two dev servies I was using:

http://local.wordpress-trunk.dev
http://local.wordpress.dev

Any tips on how I should go about finding the plugin folder? Or am I going about it wrong and should be using command terminal?

Thanks!

Scott